# FileInputFormat and its splits

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using a cluster that has hadoop 1.x. The default block size is 64MB

In Mapreduce, FileInputFormat creates split for files or blocks?

**Scenario 1 :**

Let's say there is a hdfs directory, Inside that directory I loaded two files.

```
/user/cloudera/inputfiles

  words1.txt
  words2.txt
```

The size of words1.txt is 64 MB and the size of words2.txt is 70 MB

I am using TextInputFormat as InputFormat .

Now How many splits are created by FileInputFormat ?

```
3 splits are formed because there are going to be 3 blocks

2 splits are formed because there are 2 files.
```

From the above two statements which one is correct?

**Scenario 2:**

If the size of words1.txt is 1 mb and size of words2.txt is 1 mb then how many splits are created by FileInputFormat?

Comment: In scenario 1 its 3 , 2 in scenario 2, Blocks get reused though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer